# Htaccess redirect to another file if previous not exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am translating a site from codeigniter to laravel
I want to redirect my previous image URLs to the new ones, The images are single per resource so i have used it with the resource IDs

Previous URL example
http://www.example.org/application/images/280x280/1.png

New URL example
http://www.example.org/resources/1/cover1.png

Where 1 is the resource ID

My redirect Htaccess

```
# Redirect Cover Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example(.*).org [NC]
RewriteRule ^application/images/(.*)/(.*).(jpg|png) http://example%2.org/resources/$2/cover1.png [R=301,L]
```

In the new site, I have three types for the image

cover1.png,
cover2.png,
default_cover.png

The Path stays the same

The above .htaccess code works fine for cover1.png case,

I need to write redirects that if cover1.png does not exits, it redirects to cover2.png. If that does not exist then to default_cover.png, the path for default cover is different

http://www.example.org/resources/default/default_cover.png

How can i achieve this with .htaccess

Comment: this might help you http://serverfault.com/questions/475851/redirect-to-a-url-via-htaccess-if-index-htmlphp-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following conditional rules :

```
#1)if /cover1.png !=existent file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cover1\.png !-f
#redirect "/cover1.png" to "/cover2.png"
RewriteRule ^ /cover2\.png [NC,L,R]
#2)if /cover2.png !=existent file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cover2\.png !-f
#redirect "/cover2.png" to "/default.png"
RewriteRule ^ /default.png [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: i also need to get the resource ID. How can i do that?